# Decrypt file returns empty file

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

This activity has two buttons one for encrypt and the other for decrypt. The encrypt button retrieves the files from the location where i already have it saved as "img.png" then passes it to the "EncryptFile" function for encryption and later stored as "eimg.png". Then i try the second button "decrypt" which retrieves the previously stored encrypted image. And also passes it to "decryptFile" function that will decrypt it and store it as "deimg.png".

The problem that i am facing at the moment is regarding the "deimg.png" It is stored as 0.0 Bytes,

**Encrypt Function**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

byte[] key, iv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  // Get key
  key=getKey();
  // Get IV
  iv=getIV();         
}   

public void encryptFile(View view){

 Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/img.png");
 // Write image data to ByteArrayOutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100,baos);
 // Encrypt and save the image                   
 saveFile(encrypt(key,baos.toByteArray()),"enimg.png");
}

public void decryptFile(View view){
    try {
     // Create FileInputStream to read from the encrypted image file
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/enimg.png");
         // Save the decrypted image 
         saveFile(decrypt(key, fis),"deimg.png");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void saveFile(byte[] data, String outFileName){
FileOutputStream fos=null;
try {
    fos=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+outFileName);
        fos.write(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
finally{
    try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
private byte[] encrypt(byte[] skey, byte[] data){
   SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(skey, "AES");
  Cipher cipher;
  byte[] encrypted=null;
    try {
        // Get Cipher instance for AES algorithm
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");    
        // Initialize cipher
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        // Encrypt the image byte data
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  return encrypted;
}

private byte[] decrypt(byte[] skey, FileInputStream fis){

SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(skey, "AES");

  Cipher cipher;

  byte[] decryptedData=null;

  CipherInputStream cis=null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        // Create CipherInputStream to read and decrypt the image data
        cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        // Write encrypted image data to ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        while ((cis.read(data)) != -1) {
          buffer.write(data);
        }
        buffer.flush();         
        decryptedData=buffer.toByteArray();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                fis.close();
                cis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }      
  return decryptedData;
}   
private static byte[]  getKey(){
KeyGenerator keyGen;
byte[] dataKey=null;
    try {
        // Generate 256-bit key
        keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(256); 
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    dataKey=secretKey.getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return dataKey;     
}   
private static byte[] getIV(){
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] iv = random.generateSeed(16);
return iv;
} 
}
```

Comment: 'decrypt function that returns the file'. Which file?

Comment: `decryptFile` function uses the `saveFile` to store the decrypted file, as i run two functions `saveFile(decrypt(key, fis),"name.png");`

Comment: Don't understand a word of this. Please rephrase your post so we know what you are doing.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: 'that retrieves the enrypted image'. Do you mean  'that retrieves an encrypted image'? 'trying to decrypt the file from parse'. So you downloaded an encrypted file from parse first?

Comment: I first encrypt an image, which i save aswell, and then i retrieve the encrypted image from the saved location which i try to decrypt, and that is the part that doesnt work. the decryption.

Comment: You should update your post with this info of course. As that is still very unclear. And why are you talking about parse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98784/discussion-between-anasbzr-and-greenapps).

Comment: WHat are the file sizes? You already told that the last one was zero.

Comment: the encrypted image is 2.5 mb

Comment: You should of course tell two file sizes. There are three files isn't it? The last one is 0. mb ????? Do you mean MB ?

Comment: Original is 3.8, encrypted is 2.5, the decrypted is 0

Comment: The reason you requested all this information greenapps ?

Comment: This might be a memory problem. Try with a much smaller image.

Comment: You are not encrypting a file and then decrypting it in a normal way. After decrypting you should have the same file back. Equal amount of bytes. What you are doing instead is converting a  png file to a bitmap first. Then compress it to a -probably different- png and encrypt the result. Better: encrypt the bytes of the png file right away. Then the decrypted file will be equal to the original. Understand me well. This is not the reason that your resulting file is empty. Your code works for me. I tried a file of 1MB and one of 3.5 MB. Well my originals were jpg's.

Comment: do you mind if we talk in chat ? as i just have tried to change the "PKCS5Padding" to no padding and it worked however the decrypted image is damaged, therefore you are right it should be the same, but what am i doing wrong if the code is the same ?

Comment: No i will not chat. And try with a very small image first. Stick with the code you posted.

Comment: i just tried with an image of 26.5 kb, and i got encrypted 30.28, and decrypted 32.0

Comment: 26.5 kb, ??? Please write normal:  26.5 KB, `and decrypted 32.0 ` And ???? Is it ok???

Comment: before It didn't and now after i added the fos.flush(); it worked. thank you,

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flushing your FileOutputStream, before closing it.

i.e.:

```
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```